# Stored procedure taking a long time when called from vba but quick in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, macos

I have 3 stored procedures in a database. They are very simple and similar. They all work in SQL Server and take approx 1/4 a second to run.

These stored procedures are called by some VBA code from an Excel file. Two of the three stored procedures run fine and return data in about 1/4 a second, but one of them takes approx 30 seconds to run and I don't understand why.

```
Sub USPSectorExposure()

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ctr As Integer
Dim sCode As String
Dim dtReport As Date
Dim tStart As Date

tStart = Now()

sCode = "OENN"
dtReport = "2018-02-22"

OpenDbConnection

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Code", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 20, sFund)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("dateHld", adDate, adParamInput, , dtReport)
cmd.CommandText = "uspMyTest"

Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

If rs.EOF = False Then
    MsgBox Format(Now() - tStart, "hh:mm:ss")
End If

CloseConnection

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help? Where is the procedure code? Table definitions would be a big plus also.

Comment: @SeanLange didn't think the procedure code would be needed as it works perfectly fine.

Comment: this could be classic [parameter sniffing](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Well you did say that the procedure is slow right? That means that the procedure is the issue right? It could be parameter sniffing as already suggested (very likely) or it could be that the procedure has inefficient code. Without seeing the procedure we are guessing at best.

Comment: Did you research this at all?   How did you not get @DimUser 's link in the first search results?   This is almost certainly parameter sniffing.  https://www.google.com/search?q=procedure+slow+in+application+fast+in+ssms&oq=procedure+slow+in+application+fast+in+ssms&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6631j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yeah I didn't read the question title, I usually don't because they rarely have much to do with the question. And they almost never contain vital information like this one clearly does. Obviously parameter sniffing.

Comment: @TabAlleman because this is the first time I have ever heard of parameter sniffing is probably why it didn't come up in my reasearch. Often easy and obvious when you know the answer. I'm reading his link now and trying to understand it

Comment: @mHelpMe but notice I didn't google "parameter sniffing" in my search either.  In fact, when I google the title of your question, the same link comes up in the first page of results.

Comment: @TabAlleman ok I have to be honest when I google the title of my question the link DimUser provided is not returned no idea why